# How to disable blinking cursors

Tags: eclipse, 16.10, cursor, kde5

Does anybody know how to disable the blinking cursor in KDE applications?

Using qtconfig -> CursorFlashTime -> No blinking doesn't do the job.
I especially need to disable it for Eclipse IDE, that (as stated somewhere else) uses OS settings for cursor blinking.

Any help is really appreciated, since a flashing cursors really makes me nervous.

Thanks, Felix R.

Comment: where was it stated ? Please could add a link or an explanation.

Comment: Hey @George , found it here:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/80670/

Comment: Are you app `qt5 or qt4` ?

Comment: O.k. Looks like I managed to get all KDE-Apps 'non-blinking'.
Obviously affects GTK apps  only (Firefox, Thunderbird - I don't care at all, but while coding in Eclipse this is annoying)
As I mentioned: Everything I googled so far stated that GTK should respect these preferences too. Explicitly modifying GTK settings didn't help. None of [this](http://www.jurta.org/en/prog/noblink) also...
Perhaps I'll try it in a more specific eclipse forum...

Comment: I earlier gave a suggestion about _disabling_ blinking cursor from the terminal settings under advanced settings, did you try this ?

Comment: If you got all KDE apps to work should that not be the answer you were looking for ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Eclipse is GTK. But as I already mentioned above: It is stated, that GTK reads the Qt-Preferences. But it does not for me.